# React `onClick` change between Function and Class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In offical react [tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) they first write class component:

```
class Square extends React.Component {
 render() {
   return (
     <button className="square" onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}>
       {this.props.value}
     </button>
   );
 }
}
```

and then make it a function component

```
function Square(props) {
  return (
    <button className="square" onClick={props.onClick}>
      {props.value}
    </button>
  );
}
```

Why is the `onClick` change necessary?

Thanks

Comment: What would happen if you didn't change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function component, props are accessed through the parameter `props` directly (notice how it is passed in), as it's an object. In the class component, `props` exists on the class itself, and there is not variable named `props`.

Answer (score 0):

`props` changed from being a property of the component object to being an argument passed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Function Component receives a prop as a function argument (`function Sqaure(props)`),
 while in Class Components, props are passed (or constructed from the constructor via `super(props)`) and made available via `this.props`.

Answer (score 0):

That change is not necessary but can be omitted in both cases.

You can write it in both examples like this:

```
onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}>
```

or like this which is better for performance, because it does not create a new function on every render:

```
onClick={this.props.onClick}>
```

The only difference is, where the function is coming from. In the first case it comes from the this.props since it a class component and the props are not passed directly into the render function. In the function component, the props are directly passed into the function and can be accessed by props.onClick.